# How to select a particular table field dynamically?

Tags: php, mysql

I'm designing a school portal. I want a situation where the teacher can select a particular subject from the list of subjects in my table and enter scores of students.

Afterward, the scores of the individual students of the selected subjects get entered at the database.

Below is my table structure.

[image: my table structure]

The form is generated by while loop. The Idea is to get the scores of students at once on a click.

[image: Form for the scores]

Below is my code. Please, what I'm doing wrong?

```
$moreDetails = mysqli_query(
    $con,
    "select id,reg_num,$subject,term,pin from ca where class='$class'"
);
if ($moreDetails) {
    while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($moreDetails)){
        $id = $row['id'];
        $reg = $row['reg_num'];
        $sub = $row[$subject];
        echo "
            <tr>
                <td>$id</td>
                <td>$reg</td>
                <td><label for='score'></label>
                    <input type='text' class='form-control' name='$sub' />
                    <input type='hidden' name='assessment'/>
                </td>
            </tr>
        ";
    }
}
```

Comment: you're code is vulnerable to SQL injection attacks. the hidden input serves no purpose. What are you doing wrong? good question... you failed to explain what's not working...

Comment: im quite worried about `$subject` being a column in the database...

Comment: You need to describe your precise issue. But `$sub` would be an integer value, which does not appear to be your intended results.  Use `"SELECT * FROM ca WHERE class = '$class'"` then change your form control  `<input type='text' class='form-control' name='$subject' value='$sub' />`

Comment: Who came up with your data model? Putting the subjects into different columns is not a good idea (and results in problems like yours). If you have time left, you might want to rethink your data model and put them as rows (one subject, one grade per row).

Comment: What I really want to achieve is to get individual subjects offered by students and have it graded/scored by the teacher that teaches the subject. Such that, at the click of the submit button, all the scores get entered at once.

Comment: My main challenge is how to insert/tie the scores to the students accordingly since the form input was generated by while loop. For Instance, how can one get the entries of the name field attribute of the below code  since it is a loop           <td><label for='score'></label>
                    <input type='text' class='form-control' name='score' />
                    <input type='hidden' name='assessment'/>
                </td>

Answer (score 0):

According to your comments you are looking to associate the form entries with their corresponding database rows, students, or other identifier.

In order to associate the form fields, you need to submit the [form fields as an array](http://www.php.net/manual/en/faq.html.php#faq.html.arrays) of values for your update script to process. You do this by using square brackets as the suffix of the form field name attribute. Like `name="field[]"` and optionally supply a common identifier like a database table row id, so that there are not issues with missing records.

**Data View**

```
<?php
while ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($moreDetails)) {
    $id = $row['id'];
    $reg = $row['reg_num'];
    $sub = $row[$subject];
    ?>
    <tr>
       <td><?php echo $id; ?></td>
       <td><?php echo $reg; ?></td>
       <td>
           <label for="score_<?php echo $id; ?>"></label>
           <input id="score_<?php echo $id; ?>" type="text" class="form-control" name="student[<?php echo $id; ?>][score]" />
           <input type='hidden' name='student[<?php echo $id; ?>][assessment]'/>
       </td>
    </tr>
<?php } ?>
```

Which will give you a resulting of `$_POST` value similar to this.

```
array(1) {
  ["student"]=>
  array(3) {
    ["86236762057e1df012e662"]=>
    array(2) {
      ["score"]=>
      string(1) "a"
      ["assessment"]=>
      string(1) "A"
    }
    ["40443582357e1df012e668"]=>
    array(2) {
      ["score"]=>
      string(1) "b"
      ["assessment"]=>
      string(1) "A"
    }
    ["112264948957e1df012e66c"]=>
    array(2) {
      ["score"]=>
      string(1) "c"
      ["assessment"]=>
      string(1) "A"
    }
  }
}
```

Then you need to process the array of data in an update or insert query and add your own error trapping and conditions to generate the queries to your needs.

**Insert Controller**

```
if (false === empty($_POST['student'])) {
    $queryValues = array();
    foreach ($_POST['student'] as $id => $student) {
        $queryValues[] = "('" . $id . "', '" . $student['score'] . "')";
    }
    echo 'INSERT INTO ca (id, score) VALUES ' . implode(', ', $queryValues);
}
```

**Insert Query Result**

```
INSERT INTO ca (id, score) VALUES ('86236762057e1df012e662', 'a'), ('40443582357e1df012e668', 'b'), ('112264948957e1df012e66c', 'c')
```

**Update Controller**

```
if (false === empty($_POST['student'])) {
    foreach ($_POST['student'] as $id => $student) {
        echo "UPDATE ca 
              SET score = '" . $student['score'] . "' 
              WHERE id = '" . $id . "'";
    }
}
```

**Update Queries Result**

```
UPDATE ca SET score = 'a' WHERE id = '86236762057e1df012e662'
UPDATE ca SET score = 'b' WHERE id = '40443582357e1df012e668'
UPDATE ca SET score = 'c' WHERE id = '112264948957e1df012e66c'
```

---

> As note of best practices, I strongly urge you to look into using prepared
>   statements to avoid sql injection attacks.
>   http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php